# Acumatica Grid Events

Tags: acumatica

I have a non persisted field in my Sales Order grid. I want the use to enter a value which will be used to update the unit price. i have tried catching all of the events for the grid/field but non of them trigger when the user enters a value. I do not need the update to happen on every character, just when the user hits tab to exist the field or enter.

Graph Extension:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        protected void SOLine_UsrMargin_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        protected void SOLine_UsrMargin_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);      
        }

        protected void SOLine_UsrMargin_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {  
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        public class string_PROMODET : Constant<string>
        {
            public string_PROMODET() : base("PROMODET") { }
        }

        public class string_SALESPROMO : Constant<string>
        {
            public string_SALESPROMO() : base("SALESPROMO") { }
        }

        protected void SOLine_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        protected void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        protected void SOLine_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        protected void SOLine_RowInserting(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        protected void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        protected void SOLine_RowSelecting(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (salesOrderEntry == null)
                return;

            UpdateCustomFields(cache, salesOrderEntry);
        }

        private static void UpdateCustomFields(PXCache cache, SOLine salesOrderEntry)
        {
            SOLineExt soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(salesOrderEntry);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLineExt.usrSalesPromotion>(cache, salesOrderEntry, false);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLineExt.usrSalesPromotionDetails>(cache, salesOrderEntry, false);

            using (new PXConnectionScope())
            {
                InventoryItem ii = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>
                                    .Select(new PXGraph(), salesOrderEntry.InventoryID);

                if (ii != null)
                {
                    CSAnswers promotionDetail = PXSelect<CSAnswers,
                                                Where2<
                                                    Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.noteID>>>,
                                                    And<Where<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<string_PROMODET>,
                                                        Or<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<string_PROMODET>>>>>>
                                                .Select(new PXGraph(), ii.NoteID);

                    CSAnswers promotion = PXSelect<CSAnswers,
                                            Where2<
                                                Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.noteID>>>,
                                                And<Where<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<string_SALESPROMO>,
                                                Or<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<string_SALESPROMO>>>>>>
                                            .Select(new PXGraph(), ii.NoteID);

                    INItemStats itemStats = PXSelect<INItemStats, Where<INItemStats.inventoryID, Equal<Required<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>
                                            .Select(new PXGraph(), salesOrderEntry.InventoryID);

                    if (itemStats != null)
                    {
                        cache.SetValue<SOLineExt.usrLastCost>(salesOrderEntry, itemStats.LastCost);
                        cache.SetValue<SOLineExt.usrMargin>(salesOrderEntry, ((salesOrderEntry.CuryUnitPrice / itemStats.LastCost) - 1) * 100);
                    }

                    if (promotion != null)
                    {
                        cache.SetValue<SOLineExt.usrSalesPromotion>(salesOrderEntry, promotion.Value == "1" ? true : false);
                        cache.SetValue<SOLineExt.usrSalesPromotionDetails>(salesOrderEntry, promotion.Value == "1" ? promotionDetail.Value : "");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cache Extension:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
    {
        #region UsrLastCost
        [PXDecimal]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Last Cost", Enabled = false, Visible = true, IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrLastCost { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrLastCost : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrSalesPromotion
        [PXBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sales Promotion", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual bool? UsrSalesPromotion { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrSalesPromotion : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrSalesPromotionDetails
        [PXString(64)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sales Promotion Details", Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
        public virtual string UsrSalesPromotionDetails { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrSalesPromotionDetails : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrMargin
        [PXDecimal]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Margin")]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrMargin { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrMargin : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have **CommitChanges** set to ***True*** on your custom PXGrid column?

Comment: I did not but made the change and it does not have any effect that I am looking for. I want to be notified when the cell has been updated

Comment: With **CommitChanges** set to ***True***, the framework should raise all appropriate events right after the user hits tab to exit the field. Could you please update your answer with code snippet used to define a custom SOLine field and the declaration of a custom PXGrid column?

Comment: SOLine Definition
    [PXDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Margin")]

Grid Column:
    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UsrMargin" Width="100" CommitChanges="True" />

Comment: @Rob please add the code of your DAC and Graph Extensions to the question. It will simplify the process of answering to your question

Comment: Most of the code in the graph extension is there for me to determine which events are thrown and when.

Comment: @Rob you should get event triggered if you have published customization with **CommitChanges** set to **True**. Try to click on other tab and check if you are getting any event triggered. If you got then try to republish the customization project.

Comment: It does indeed look alright, try iisreset/republish customization. Try to use a surefire method to assess whether or not the events aren't called like: throw new PXException() on first line.

Comment: Also in folder CstPublished of the Acumatica IIS virtual directory, check if the page does contain CommitChanges="True". The CstPublished folder should contains the merged extension you did to the original page.